Chi square test is always successful, what am I doing wrong?
I was applying the chi-square goodness of fit test to a big array of observed data and an array of theoretical data with a free parameter (in the form of a multiplier), to determine the value of the multiplier that produced the best fit between the two. However, the test was concluding that the fit was successful for all values of the multiplier, which was suspicious, so I wrote a small script to test the chi-square and something is indeed wrong in the way I am using it. Here it is:
import numpy as np
import scipy.stats as stats

multiplier = [-250,-10,-3,1,4,8,23,78,950,1000000]
a = [1,1,1,1,1,1,1]
b = [4,4,4,4,4,4,4]
n = len(multiplier)
chi_p_values = np.zeros(n)
myp = 0.01
foundfit = 0

def adapt_for_chi(a,b): # a = array of observed frequencies, b = array of theoretical expected frequencies for the proposed distribution 
    return [(np.sum(b)/np.sum(a))*i for i in a] # This way, sum(a) and sum(b) will be the same (requirement for stats.chisquare)

for i in range(n):
    a_multiplied = [multiplier[i]*freq for freq in a]
    a_multiplied_for_chi = adapt_for_chi(a_multiplied,b)
    chi_square_test_statistic,p_value = stats.chisquare(a_multiplied_for_chi,b) 
    chi_p_values[i] = p_value
    if p_value > myp:
        foundfit += 1

print('p-values: ',chi_p_values)
print('Successful tests: ',foundfit)

The result should be that the fit is only good for multiplier = 4, so I would expect to get Successful tests: 1 but instead I get:
p values:  [1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1.]
Successful tests:  10

What am I doing wrong? It must be something so simple but I can't seem to figure it out.

"This way, sum(a) and sum(b) will be the same " - and as all values of a are the same, and all values of b are the same, your adapted values will all be the same as your a values. You should use better, more varied data than this...

@ThierryLathuille Oh, you're right. But even then, once I multiply the array 'a' by the different values stored in the 'multiplier' array, the only one that should give a correct fit is 'multiplier = 1'. I can't understand why the test is successful for all values.

Again, because once you go through adapt_for_chi, your a_multiplied_for_chi will always be [4.0, 4.0, 4.0, 4.0, 4.0, 4.0, 4.0], whatever your multiplier, since you requested the sum to be the same as the sum of a.

@ThierryLathuille Ohhhh I see! Sorry, I had misunderstood. So, given that the chi-square test in Python requires for the sum of frequencies in both tested arrays to be the same, I suppose that for 'flat' distributions another statistical test is better, right?
